# What is the difference between engine approach and language approach in terms of saving game data?

Tags: unity, c#, savegame

I was asked to find a way to somehow save gamedata for a game we (my friends and I) are making and i found that there is something called engine and language approach. I have found something i would call language approach because it relies mostly on System libs but cannot find anything on the engine approach. Are scriptable objects the way of saving data by engine approach ? if so how do i combine them in one savefile ?
Game engine we are using is Unity and we're writing code in C#.

Comment: I don't know more about engine approach or language approach but at runtime Scriptable Objects are read only

Comment: I have never heard these terms in the context of Unity. Maybe the terminology stems from a different game engine which actually has a native savegame system? Because the Unity engine doesn't really have one. You have to implement your own.

Comment: Ok. So saving game must be done by serializing all data I want to save and then throwing it to a file ... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you cite a reference for where you came across these terms "engine approach" and "language approach"? I haven't heard them in common use, so they might be specific to a particular context or author's framing.

Comment: that could be a problem because the names were given me by my kind of boss ... but if noone here seem to know them i guess he just dug it realllllly deep in idk what because i did not find any reference to them on web... i'd say the problem is closed due to noone knowing these terms. Thank you all for help

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask your "kind of boss" then. If you can relay what they say, we may yet be able to help offer more info here.